# How to model REST URIs from a dynamic XML tree

Tags: xml, rest, jersey, jquery-dynatree

I'm a newbie with REST approach and I have a challenge to solve with it.
I have a xml tree on my server and it could be dynamically changed both in deepness and contents at each time.
That means I should to find a way to get dynamically the root node A, then its children, for example nodes B-C-D, then the sub-tree associated with node C (nodes C.1,C.2,C.3) and the leaves associated with C.1 that are for example C.1.1 and C.1.2.
But In the next time I will have a different xml file and so the nodes of tree will change.
How can i model my REST URIs with this dynamic tree structure?
Have you any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

clizia

Answer (score 0):

I respectfully submit that an endpoint structure that fluid is going to cause all kinds of problems. I'm not aware of Jersey cleanly supporting what you want, nor any other java library for that matter.

I guess you could hack something together yourself, but I would strongly discourage it. For instance, you could make endpoints for each level of the tree, like

/level0/{id}/level1/{id}/level2/{id}

Without knowing your business requirements, it's hard to give alternative suggestions, but perhaps just returning the tree as the response from a single endpoint would be better?

Comment: On the client side I use dynatree(jQuery)and on the server side I have an xml file that changes sometimes in in deepness(I can't establish how many level there are) and in contents.Using the lazy loading of dynatree the client explore step by step the corresponding xml file on server.That mean, at first request the client receive the root node, at second lazy request clicking on the root the client receives all the children of the root.When the client clicks on one of the child of the first subtree,he receives the the children of the node clicked and so on. And I need to use Rest approach.